# unable to run tensorboard on anaconda prompt

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda, environment

I have installed tensorflow in a conda environment called `ml`. I opened Anaconda prompt and activate the environment to run my codes. Then, I type `tensorboard --logdir="C:\Users\cyh\Documents\Programming\Python\tensorflow\logs\Cats-vs-dogs-CNN_1537350313\"`, but it shows error. It basically shows the same error regardless of what arguments I type after `tensorboard`. The error is

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\cyh\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\python.exe"
"C:\Users\cyh\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\ml\Scripts\tensorboard.exe" --logdir="C:\Users\cyh\Documents\Programming\Python\tensorflow\logs\Cats-vs-dogs-CNN_1537350313\"'
```

So it says it cannot create a process using the python.exe in that particular directory, but the directory is simply wrong as I name my environment `ml` instead of `tensorflow`. How to fix this problem? Or is it necessary to name the environment `tensorflow`?

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me too.
I moved anaconda from a drive to another. It turns out on installation the path is written into the exe file for tensorborad.exe and you can fix it by opening the file into notepad or any other text editor then finding and replacing faulty path into correct path

[image: Replace Path in notepad]